# How to use the Embedded Ruby -%> to slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

How to do this `<%= -%>` in slim, for example:

```
= "#{state}" -
```

or

```
= "#{state} -"
```

Answer (score 1):

The support for no-space around tags (`<%= -%>`) should be available via smart text plugin (https://github.com/slim-template/slim/blob/master/doc/smart.md) that should be included by default with slim, so a simple `require 'slim/smart'` and you should be able to just do the following (without `=`):

```
p
  #{state}
```